# Image for Open Graph protocol

Tags: magento2, product-images, open-graph

I'm getting image for Open Graph protocol with following code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()); ?>" />
```

But it gives me the small image with 80x80px size:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/80x80/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/0/1/01.jpg">
```

Now I have such folder structure:

[image]

How can I get the other size from this folder or non cached images?

Comment: In you theme `etc/view.xml`  find image id `product_base_image` and check the image `type`, if this select image id that type will be `image`, if type is `small_image`  change to `image` 
If type is `image` only then respective size (width & height) will  80*80 change that one to a proper size as you required. and flush cache and check respective product detail page.

Comment: What is the file path of the xml that you're talking about Kanhaiya?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<?php
$imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$ogImage = $imagehelper->init($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')
                       ->constrainOnly(FALSE)
                       ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                       ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                       ->resize(250, 250)
                       ->getUrl();
?>

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $ogImage; ?>" />
```

Comment: Does this just increase the small image size (i.e. won't it lose resolution)?